# Vega-lite Deneb: Local time to UTC Time

Tags: vega-lite, vega, deneb

I am working on a Power BI project where I need to bring time from different timezones. Please see the below image.

[example of my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqdL9.png)

In order to do this, i need to use the utc time as my starting point and then do the offsets (-3, +5 etc).
This is because the same report is going to be used from people around different countries.

I found the below code on the internet but this code takes in to account the local time.
How can i take hte utc one instead of local? I tried to solve it but i did not achieve it.

[where the parameter i try to change is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCJWe.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A circular clock visualization showing the current time.",
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100,
  "signals": [
    {"name": "centerX", "init": "width/2"},
    {"name": "centerY", "init": "height/2"},
    {"name": "radiusRef", "init": "min(width,height)*0.8"},
    {"name": "sizeFactor", "init": "radiusRef/400"},
    {"name": "outerRadius", "init": "radiusRef/2"},
    {"name": "innerRadius", "init": "radiusRef/2 - (10 * sizeFactor)"},
    {
      "name": "currentDate",
      "init": "now()-25200000",
      "on": [{"events": {"type": "timer", "throttle": 1000}, "update": "now()-25200000"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "currentHour",
      "init": "hours(currentDate)+minutes(currentDate)/60",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "currentDate"},
          "update": "hours(currentDate)+minutes(currentDate)/60"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currentMinute",
      "init": "minutes(currentDate)+seconds(currentDate)/60",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "currentDate"},
          "update": "minutes(currentDate)+seconds(currentDate)/60"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currentSecond",
      "init": "seconds(currentDate)",
      "on": [
        {"events": {"signal": "currentDate"}, "update": "seconds(currentDate)"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "hours",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "sequence", "start": 0, "stop": 12, "step": 1, "as": "hour"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "centerX - cos(PI/2 + (datum.hour * PI/6)) * (outerRadius - (outerRadius-innerRadius)/2)",
          "as": "x"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "centerY - sin(PI/2 + (datum.hour * PI/6)) * (outerRadius - (outerRadius-innerRadius)/2)",
          "as": "y"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "centerX - cos(PI/2 + (datum.hour * PI/6)) * (innerRadius - 25 * max(sizeFactor, 0.4))",
          "as": "xHour"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "centerY - sin(PI/2 + (datum.hour * PI/6)) * (innerRadius - 25 * max(sizeFactor, 0.4))",
          "as": "yHour"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "minutes",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "sequence", "start": 0, "stop": 60, "step": 1, "as": "minute"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "centerX - cos(PI/2 + (datum.minute * PI/30)) * (outerRadius - (outerRadius-innerRadius)/3)",
          "as": "x"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "centerY - sin(PI/2 + (datum.minute * PI/30)) * (outerRadius - (outerRadius-innerRadius)/2)",
          "as": "y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "hourScale",
      "domain": {"data": "hours", "field": "hour"},
      "range": [0, {"signal": "2*PI"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "minutesScale",
      "domain": {"data": "minutes", "field": "minute"},
      "range": [0, {"signal": "2*PI"}]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "startAngle": {"value": 0},
          "endAngle": {"signal": "2*PI"},
          "outerRadius": {"signal": "outerRadius"},
          "fill": {"value": "transparent"},
          "stroke": {"value": "black"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "startAngle": {"value": 0},
          "endAngle": {"signal": "2*PI"},
          "outerRadius": {"signal": "innerRadius"},
          "fill": {"value": "#FCFCFC"},
          "opacity": {"value": 0.6},
          "stroke": {"value": "black"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "minutes"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"signal": "pow(2*sizeFactor, 2)"},
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "angle": {"signal": "datum.minute*6"},
          "shape": {"value": "m 0 -5 v 10"},
          "stroke": {"value": "black"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "hours"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"signal": "pow(2*sizeFactor, 2)"},
          "angle": {"signal": "datum.hour*30"},
          "shape": {"value": "m -5 -5 h 10 l -5 10 l -5 -10 Z"},
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "hours"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"field": "xHour"},
          "y": {"field": "yHour"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "text": {"signal": "datum.hour === 0 ? 12 : datum.hour"},
          "fontSize": {"signal": "25*max(sizeFactor, 0.4)"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"signal": "pow(2*sizeFactor, 2)"},
          "shape": {"value": "M 0 0 h-1 l 1 -160 l 1 160 h-1"},
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "fill": {"value": "red"},
          "stroke": {"value": "red"},
          "strokeSize": {"value": 2},
          "strokeCap": {"value": "round"}
        },
        "update": {"angle": {"signal": "currentSecond*6"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"signal": "pow(2*sizeFactor, 2)"},
          "shape": {
            "value": "M 0 0 h -2 l -5 -30 l 7 -120 l 7 120 l -5 30 h -2 "
          },
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "stroke": {"value": "grey"},
          "strokeCap": {"value": "round"},
          "strokeWidth": {"signal": "2* min(sizeFactor, 1)"}
        },
        "update": {"angle": {"signal": "currentMinute*6"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"signal": "pow(2*sizeFactor, 2)"},
          "shape": {"value": "M 0 0 h-3 l -4 -30 l 7 -80 l 7 80 l -4 30 h -3"},
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "stroke": {"value": "grey"},
          "strokeCap": {"value": "round"},
          "strokeWidth": {"signal": "2* min(sizeFactor, 1)"},
          "zIndex": {"value": 1}
        },
        "update": {"angle": {"signal": "currentHour*30"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "startAngle": {"value": 0},
          "endAngle": {"signal": "2*PI"},
          "outerRadius": {"signal": "6*sizeFactor"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "stroke": {"value": "grey"},
          "zIndex": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "startAngle": {"value": 0},
          "endAngle": {"signal": "2*PI"},
          "innerRadius": {"signal": "outerRadius"},
          "outerRadius": {"signal": "outerRadius + 14 * sizeFactor"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"},
          "stroke": {"value": "grey"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot team

Please see the code below

I am trying to create some clocks showing the time in different timezones. I develop it in the Power BI Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try and create a measure in your datasource using the UTCNOW function and using this in deneb.

For example:

```
UTC_Current_Datetime = UTCNOW()
```